# 2D utilities for drawing boxes, text, etc. in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, text, three.js, drawing, 2d

Our library [ApiNATOMY](http://apinatomy.org/home) renders a tree-map to navigate a hierarchical space (like human anatomy, for instance). We used to use nested `<div>` elements for every tile, but the re-flow process was a constant source of slowdown. We've now switched to pure WebGL (Three.js), and got a remarkable performance boost.

However, this did lose us the convenience of HTML-like markup. It now requires 10-20 lines of code to draw a box, and another 10-20 to render some text. Having things stay centered when the box is re-sized is also a manual job, and I don't even dare dream of automatic line-breaks. Then there's the problem of `THREE.FontUtils` being an incredibly slow way to render text. I've found a way to do it with a [separate canvas](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Texture-From-Canvas.html), but that also requires a lot of manual code, and is more inflexible w.r.t. sizing.

So my question is: Is there some library of utility classes/functions to make these sorts of 2D jobs in Three.js easier and more robust? Alternatively, any general tips or references?

(Note: There will still be 3D aspects to ApiNATOMY, so a pure 2D renderer is not an option.)